# Allow access to S3 bucket only for authenticated users of application

Tags: amazon-s3, acl, restriction

I'm launching in few weeks my application on Playstore.
In this app, registered users will have possibility to see picture of other users (like a social media app) and will have possibility to upload,delete their own pictures.
These pictures should be visible only for registered users of the app.

I created a bucket in AWS S3 to store all of these images, but this bucket is currently set as "Public access".
How can I change this setting without blocking access to pictures for registered users?

Users will be able to authenticate through Firebase by using SMA like Facebook/Instagram, Gmail and phone number.

Thanks a lot for your help.[image]

I already tried to block public access but it seems like I have to add some specific rules (ACL??) to allow users of the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **Pre-signed URLs**

Presigned URLs are time-limited URLs that grant temporary access to specific S3 objects. You can generate presigned URLs on the server side and provide them to your authenticated users, allowing them to access the private S3 objects without exposing your S3 bucket or making it public.

> *Here's how you can use presigned URLs to implement your desired functionality:*
>
> When a user uploads an image, your app's backend generates a presigned
> URL for the S3 object in which the image will be stored. This URL will
> have a limited expiration time, typically a few minutes to a few
> hours. The app then provides this presigned URL to the user's device.
> The user's device uses the presigned URL to directly upload the image
> to the S3 bucket.

By using presigned URLs, you maintain control over access to your S3 objects while providing a secure and temporary way for authenticated users to interact with them. Presigned URLs also ensure that users don't need to know your S3 bucket's credentials or have direct access to the bucket, enhancing the security of your app and data.

> For more info you can refer these aws documents -
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example_s3_Scenario_PresignedUrl_section.html

Answer (score 0):

**Using pre-signed URLs is an effective way to grant temporary access to specific objects in your Amazon S3 bucket to authenticated users of your application**

Let me show you --how to proceed

1)Create an IAM Role and grant it full access to an S3 Bucket. Under the 'Security Credentials' tab, generate an Access Key and Secret Key.

2. Create an S3 Bucket that is private and has blocked public access.
   [image]

"I want my IAM user to have programmatic(using URL) access to a specific S3 bucket, allowing them to upload and retrieve objects even if public access is blocked".
so, We have to attach some policies to this S3 Bucket

```
`{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Statement1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
    }
]}`
```

.....
3) After this go to your backend server

```
const { GetObjectCommand }=require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');
const { getSignedUrl }=require('@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner')
```

Install this package and grab the thing mentioned above

The primary use of the "get object command" is to retrieve the content of a stored object
and getSignedUrl generates a secure URL that provides temporary access to our authenticated user of our application

and our APP user  dont need to have the access of that bucket.

**using the credentials of our IAM user we will generate this URL so this URL will have access to see the object**

4. configuration to genrate a url to see object from AWS

```js
    const config = {
      region:process.env.REGION,
       credentials: {
     accessKeyId:process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
     secretAccessKey:process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
       }
}
```

This config object contain the valid key of our IAM user which have access to S3 Bucket

const s3 = new S3Client(config);

s3-> It is used to send requests to various AWS services, including Amazon S3, and it returns a promise that resolves with the response from the service.

```js
app.post("/generate-presigned-url-to-access-object", (req, res) => {

 const bucketName='bucketname';
 const objectKey = req.body.objectKey; // Object key received from the frontend

  // Generate a presigned URL for the specified object
 const command=new GetObjectCommand({
        Bucket:bucketName,
        Key:objectKey,

    })
    const url=await getSignedUrl(s3Client,command)


    // Send the presigned URL to the frontend
    res.json({ presignedUrl: url });
  });
});
```

**key is the name of object which u want to access**
If you already have an object stored in your AWS S3 bucket, retrieve the object's key and test it out.

Otherwise, when you upload an object to your AWS S3 bucket, you will receive a key  store that key  in your database.
When a client wants to view the image, they can send a request to the server using that key to generate a URL."

If you want to learn how to upload an object to AWS S3 using pre-signed URLs, check out my story on Medium-https://medium.com/@gurpreetsingh_28520